# Can anybody help with the integral of \dfrac{(\cos(x)·\sin(x))}{(\sin(x)+\cos(x))}.

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals

Evaluate:

$ \displaystyle \int _{0}^{\frac{π}{2}} \dfrac{(\cos(x)·\sin(x))}{(\sin(x)+\cos(x))}$

Comment: You just have to devided the numerator and denominator by $sin(x)cos(x)$ and make the substitution $x=arctan(y)$ .

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin x \cos x}{\sin x+\cos x}dx=
\frac{1}{2\sqrt2}\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin 2x}{\cos(x-\pi/4)}dx=
\frac{1}{2\sqrt2}\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}\frac{\cos 2t}{\cos t}dt \\
=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\left[2\cos t-\frac{1}{\cos t}\right]dt=
\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\left[2\sin t -\log\left|\frac{1+\sin t}{\cos t}\right|\right]_{0}^{\pi/4}\\
=1-\frac{\log(1+\sqrt2)}{\sqrt2}.
$$

Comment: Thank you, I did the numerator but hadn't found a form for the denominator, that's very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Start with a substitution $$ u=\tan (x/2)$$

Then you have $$du = (1/2)(1+\tan ^2 (x/2)) dx $$ and $$ \sin x= \frac {2u}{1+u^2}$$ and $$\cos x = \frac {1-u^2}{1+u^2}$$

Simplify and continue to get the result.

Comment: I completely forgot about this substitution - thank you very much.